# Apache2 mod_proxy_fcgi closes a connection after each request

Tags: apache-2.2, connection, fastcgi, mod-proxy, socket

I set up `mod_proxy_fcgi` do go with apache and `php-fpm`. If I read the FCGI spec correctly, the typical flow for the communication between a server is to keep the connections between the web server and the FastCGI server open while they are active. However I observe different behaviour. Apache seems to close the connection after each request.

Here are the relevant parts of `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

...

ProxyPass / fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ ttl=120
ProxyErrorOverride on
```

I set `LogLevel` to `debug`. I get the following logs when I run a few requests in a loop (there is very little time between the requests, so I really wouldn't expect any timeouts):

```
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.338770 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] mod_authz_core.c(828): [client 127.0.0.1:36279] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.338793 2013] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(120): [client 127.0.0.1:36279] AH01060: set r->filename to proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.338802 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] mod_proxy.c(1083): [client 127.0.0.1:36279] AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0)
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.338807 2013] [proxy_http:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] mod_proxy_http.c(2174): [client 127.0.0.1:36279] AH01113: HTTP: declining URL fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.338812 2013] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(944): [client 127.0.0.1:36279] AH01076: url: fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.338816 2013] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(954): [client 127.0.0.1:36279] AH01078: serving URL //127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.338821 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] proxy_util.c(2013): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (127.0.0.1)
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.338826 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] proxy_util.c(2065): [client 127.0.0.1:36279] AH00944: connecting //127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.338887 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] proxy_util.c(2187): [client 127.0.0.1:36279] AH00947: connected /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.339232 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 29880:tid 140162482755328] proxy_util.c(2028): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (127.0.0.1)
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.343980 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] mod_authz_core.c(828): [client 127.0.0.1:36282] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.344001 2013] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(120): [client 127.0.0.1:36282] AH01060: set r->filename to proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.344018 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] mod_proxy.c(1083): [client 127.0.0.1:36282] AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0)
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.344024 2013] [proxy_http:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] mod_proxy_http.c(2174): [client 127.0.0.1:36282] AH01113: HTTP: declining URL fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.344028 2013] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(944): [client 127.0.0.1:36282] AH01076: url: fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.344033 2013] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(954): [client 127.0.0.1:36282] AH01078: serving URL //127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.344038 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] proxy_util.c(2013): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (127.0.0.1)
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.344043 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] proxy_util.c(2065): [client 127.0.0.1:36282] AH00944: connecting //127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.344082 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] proxy_util.c(2187): [client 127.0.0.1:36282] AH00947: connected /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/info.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Mon Oct 07 12:43:49.344397 2013] [proxy:debug] [pid 28752:tid 140162457577216] proxy_util.c(2028): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (127.0.0.1)
```

I see this line `FCGI: has released connection for (127.0.0.1)` repeating over and over again. I looked inside Apache2 implementation. Here are the relevant bits:

```
PROXY_DECLARE(int) ap_proxy_release_connection(const char *proxy_function,
                                               proxy_conn_rec *conn,
                                               server_rec *s)
{
    ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_DEBUG, 0, s, APLOGNO(00943)
                 "%s: has released connection for (%s)",
                 proxy_function, conn->worker->s->hostname);
    connection_cleanup(conn);

    return OK;
}

...

PROXY_DECLARE(int) ap_proxy_connection_reusable(proxy_conn_rec *conn)
{
    proxy_worker *worker = conn->worker;

    return ! (conn->close || !worker->s->is_address_reusable || worker->s->disablereuse);
}

...

static apr_status_t connection_cleanup(void *theconn)
{
    ...

    /* determine if the connection need to be closed */
    if (!ap_proxy_connection_reusable(conn)) {
        apr_pool_t *p = conn->pool;
        apr_pool_clear(p);
        conn = apr_pcalloc(p, sizeof(proxy_conn_rec));
        conn->pool = p;
        conn->worker = worker;
        apr_pool_create(&(conn->scpool), p);
        apr_pool_tag(conn->scpool, "proxy_conn_scpool");
    }

    ...
}
```

I put some additional logs and recompiled Apache and I get that both `conn->close` is true and `worker->s->is_address_reusable` is false. Any clues as to what is misconfigured?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you testing?  More specifically, are you sending HTTP 1.0 requests?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I send requests with curl in a loop.

Comment: I'm still not like 100% positive the connections are closed. If you have a bullet-proof method for testing this, I would gladly try it.

Comment: Basically, I'm writing a FastCGI server myself and there I'm certain that connections are being closed. Therefore I chose to test with php-fpm to see whether it's my server or Apache that causes the problems. This is what I observe.

Comment: As far as I can tell, curl defaults to HTTP 1.1. I'll specify `--http1.1` explicitly and retest.